# How many times an article appears in each tag?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I'm having trouble trying to figure out this one. I have these 3 tables: a tags list, an article list, a relation list.

They go as follow:

**Tags**

```
 id | name
-----------
 1  | tag1
 2  | tag2
 3  | tag3
 4  | noArticles
```

**Articles**

```
 id | title    | active
------------------------
 1  | product1 | 1
 2  | product2 | 1
 3  | product3 | 0
 4  | product4 | 1
 5  | product5 | 0
 6  | product6 | 1
```

**Relations**

```
 article_id | tag_id
---------------------
     1      |   1
     1      |   3
     2      |   3
     3      |   1
     3      |   2
     4      |   2
     4      |   3
     5      |   2
     6      |   1
     6      |   2
     6      |   1
```

I know an article can only have a tag once. Well, the query i want is something like this:

**How many times article N (lets say... 4) appears in each tag that HAS ACTIVE ARTICLES?**

The answer would be something like:

```
 name | times 
--------------
 tag1 |  0    
 tag2 |  1    
 tag3 |  1
```

I'll make sure the article I'm searching is active beforehand.

Comment: Ah! I'll show the answer. Just a minute.

Comment: +1 Now it is clear what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the edit on your question it is now clear what you're looking for:

```
SELECT t.name, SUM(r.article_id = 4) times FROM tags t
LEFT JOIN relations r ON r.tag_id = t.id
JOIN articles a ON r.article_id = a.id
WHERE a.active = 1
GROUP BY t.id
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11ed5/1).

I guess you already know that the `4` in there is the `article N` :)

Answer (score -1):

Tried this sentence, it work fine for me:

```
SELECT  
    `Tags`.`name`,
    `Articles`.`active`,
    COUNT(`Relations`.`Tags_id`) AS `count`
    FROM     `Relations`,`Articles`,`Tags`

    WHERE   
             `Articles`.`id`  =  `Relations`.`article_id`  
        AND  `Tags`.`id`  =  `Relations`.`tag_id`  

    GROUP BY `Relations`.`article_id`
```

Comment: Thanks, man. But actually I wanted to see **ALL TAGS that have active articles** and if an specific article **has or has not** each of those tags.